# Golang WriteHeaderAndJson returns wrong result

Tags: go

I got the following code running in azure which returns wrong output when calling the api from Azure cloudshell, but returns correct result when I run it locally on my Ubuntu terminal.

```
type S struct {
Properties SProperties `json:"properties"`
}

type SProperties struct {
    Available bool `json:"available"`
}

result = S{
    Properties: SProperties{
        Available:            true,
    },
}

ContainerServiceRessource.SyncOperationContext.Response.WriteHeaderAndJson(200, result, "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
```

Expected output:

`{
    "properties": {
      "available": true
    }
 }`

actual output:
`{\n  \"properties\": {\n   \"available\": true\n  }\n }`

I don't know what is going on.
I got 3 apis in the same format just returning different availabilities. two of them are not working well like stated above and the last one is working as expected.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Show the relevant code (the `WriteHeaderAndJson` method).

Comment: It is here https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful/blob/master/response.go

Comment: The actual code is [here](https://github.com/emicklei/go-restful/blob/1905f349c059305e2785c36f986dbaf9e691898c/entity_accessors.go#L141). There's not enough to go on here.  My guess is that response body is correct and that something [quotes](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Quote) that output for display.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that

Comment: The actual output looks like the output of a json string passed to json.Marshal, i.e. json marshaling *"twice"*. So my guess is that the `result` variable in your example code is a `string` containing json in your actual code, and not `S`. You know that `WriteHeaderAndJson` does the json encoding and that you don't need to marshal the output yourself?

Comment: @mkopriva The current code shows how I construct the json string, I do not marshall it before pasting to WriteHeaderAndJson, I also have another APi using the same struct as stated above wity WriteHeaderAndJson and that on happens to return the correct format.